# Is it possible to make GRUB2 look similar to burg?

Tags: grub2, themes

I would like to stick to GRUB since it seems to be more actively developed and the entries are automatically updated after a kernel update. However I love the look of the Burg themes (especially sora_clean).

Are there themes available for GRUB2 which have a similar look? I especially would like a "folded view", showing only one entry per OS (by default), and a the installed OSes being shown as symbols, instead of listed text.

I would also be grateful for installation instructions along with the theme suggestions.

Comment: what are you looking for beyond the detail here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/115432/change-boot-entry-names-and-grub-background)

Comment: That answer covers some of it, thanks. If possible however I would like to replace text with logos, such as with the burg "sora" theme (http://ubuntuguide.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/os_logo1.png)

Comment: ... "replace text with logos" - as far as I can gather, that isnt grub2 functionality - that is one of the reasons BURG exists.

Comment: too bad BURG is dead... So the proper answer is "No" I guess. 
If you want to post that as an answer with the link you posted earlier (to the other question explaining how to customize the background and the text) I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grub does have some theming capabilities - we already have a great Q&A that covers how to change the Grub background and changing the text menu colours:

- [Change boot entry names and grub background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115432/change-boot-entry-names-and-grub-background)
- [How can I get some nice eye candy themes for Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub)

However, to answer your very specific question, it is not possible to convert the text selection in Grub2 to Iconised symbols.  This is one of the reasons why BURG was created.

UbuntuForums has a great thread to cover Grub2 themes and more importantly screenshots showing the themes that can be achieved.

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823915

[image]

(post #61)

This screenshot was created by:

1. adding a background image
2. installing a grub-font
3. installing grub-icons for each OS (called a class)

I'm loathed to duplicate such a great tutorial here as per the first post in the thread.  Its pretty much self-explanatory on the steps you need to do.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give you the bounty once the system lets me.

Answer (score 1):

For grub2 themes see:
http://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/grub-extras/themes.tgz

And http://apebox.org/wordpress/linux/261/

I don't have the time now but I will try to add full instructions for using them later.

In short, extract the theme directory (anywhere will do, `/boot/grub/theme_directory/` makes sense), add `GRUB_THEME=/boot/grub/theme_directory/theme.txt` to /etc/default/grub and run `sudo update-grub`.