# changing system terminal colours?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, command-line, gnome-terminal, personalization

So I have my computer set up just the way I want, with gnome 3 in my favorite color scheme, and the terminal in a matching background/text color scheme. Even the login screen has my Desktop background.

However it is a little jarring when I shut down/use grubby and its in the default maroon and white scheme. Is there any way to change this to make it more similar to my own color scheme in terminal?

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147462/how-can-i-change-the-tty-colors) work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You might find installing grub-customizer to be useful.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install grub-customizer

Also it may interest you to take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115432/change-boot-entry-names-and-grub-background/).

Comment: The default purple gets set in `/lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub` (background_color 44,0,30) where the 3 numbers are the RGB colour value. All other information I think is here and in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal, right click anywhere, and select "Profiles --> Profile Preferences." From here, use the Colors and Background tabs.